# lein-less not running on figwheel start or when a .less file changes

Tags: less, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

I'm trying to setup a clojurescript project that uses the lein-less plugin to compile .less files. I should say I'm new to clojurescript. The problem is that it doesn't seem to run. It doesn't run when I run "lein figwheel" and neither when I change a .less file.

This is my project.cljs

```
(defproject fed-repo "0.1.0"
    :description "Frontend Repository"
    :dependencies [
        [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
        [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]
        [org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha22"]
    ]
    :plugins [
        [lein-less "1.7.5"]
        [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.2"]
        [lein-figwheel "0.5.0-4"]
    ]
    :less {
        :source-paths ["src"]
        :target-path "resources/public/css"
    }
    :hooks [
        leiningen.less
        leiningen.cljsbuild
    ]
    :cljsbuild {
        :builds [
            {
                :id "dev"
                :source-paths ["src"]
                :figwheel true
                :compiler {
                    :main "fed-repo.core"
                    :asset-path "js/out"
                    :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
                    :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

What is wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Under `:less` the values for the keys `:source-paths` and `:target-path` need to go to actual files. You seem to have stopped at the directory.</del>

Here's a working example:

```
:less {:source-paths ["src/less/"]
       :target-path "resources/public/css/"}
```

Another issue is that you are not telling Figwheel where to hot code reload `css` from. Example:

```
:figwheel { :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"] }
```

With the set up so far there is still no `.less` -> `.css` file generation. You could have a terminal open that is dedicated to running `lein less once`. After changing the `.less` file run that command. Alternatively automatic generation can be done with the command `lein less auto`.

Comment: According to [lein-less v.1.7.5 documentation](https://github.com/montoux/lein-less) no explicit files are necessary, and by trial doesn't seem to work. Edited accordingly.

Comment: That was a pretty serious edit. It is certainly no longer my working example. You should have written your own answer instead.